# Is there a way of coloring cmdlet examples in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, colors, powershell-cmdlet

I know that multiple colors are easily available in PowerShell, but it seems that the default is not to use them.  If I enter, for example `get-help Get-Process -examples` I get several screens of examples all in the same foreground color.

Is there any way I can set such output to have multiple colors, for example, for headings, user input, output, and so on?  It would vastly increase the readability and indeed the usefulness of such a large chunk of text.

Ideally, if this is possible, there'd be different color schemes to choose between.

But *is* it possible?

Comment: the help system is pure text. there is no coloring info in the file AT ALL. you can see this by reading the file in any text editor/viewer. heck, the files seem to all end with `.txt`. [*grin*] ///// so ... it's possible, but someone would need to write a script to do it.

Comment: Related discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8692